# How do I import images to a File Field using DataGrab?

Tags: file-uploads, import, datagrab

I am importing data using DataGrab and need to be able to link image files correctly in the File field.

I tried using this for the path to the image file:

> {filedir_1}myimage.jpg

However, it doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Here are the values I am uploading:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember running into this and the problem for me was running Synchronize ( Content > Files > File Upload Preferences ) for the upload destination. You also have to have previously uploaded the images yourself via ftp, as DataGrab doesn't do that. Here's a good rundown from the developer on images from a [forum thread](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/forums/viewthread/724/):

> I am currently writing some better documentation on how to import
>   images, but in the meantime, this is the best way to do it:
>
> 1) DataGrab won’t actually copy the images to the new server - you’ll
>   have to FTP them to a valid File Upload directory.
>
> When you have copied the files to the correct place, you’ll need to
>   synchronise the folder from the Control Panels Content > Files > File
>   Upload Preferences page.
>
> 2) The images will need in the correct format in the CSV/XML file.
>
> This format is {filedir_1}your_image_name.jpg
>   where the 1 is the id of the upload folder you have copied the files
>   to. You can usually do this with a search and replace in the file.

Comment: Hi, it sounds like I am pretty close as I have done almost exactly that. The photos have been uploaded to the server and I did sync it. I just need to go back and double check. I will append the entry above to reflect a row of data.

Comment: If you look in the db in exp_files are there any rows created reflecting the image import at all?

Comment: Hi Romans 8, I looked in the images folder and there was one image that was preventing syncing and someone else had uploaded images to the wrong folder, so it was a combination of issues. However, the {filedir_x} prefix on the images does work and synching is the proper step 2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it:)